# why am i not able to use this( RaisedButton) keyword?

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvEh0.jpg)im not able to use this keyword

i was expecting to use this keywordim not able to use this keyword

Answer (score 2):

Its deprecated, replaced by `ElevatedButton`.
[New Buttons and Button Themes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#context)

Answer (score 2):

the `RaisedButton` is deprecated, it's replaced by `ElevatedButton`:

replace:

```
RaisedButton(/*...*/),
```

with:

```
ElevatedButton(/*...*/),
```

check all new migrations here:

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#context

Answer (score 1):

`RaisedButton` is deprecated. Replace it with `ElevatedButton`

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('question'),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('answer1'),
                onPressed: null,
              ),
            ],
          ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

`Raised button` is deprecated use `Elevated Button`

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(children:[
              Text('question'),
              ElevatedButton(child: Text('answer1'),onPressed: null),
            ],),
      ),
    );
```